# Draw stacked horizontal bar chart with Average line using ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to create a stacked horizontal bar chart with an average line on each bar using the ChartJS library. I tried several times and searched on the Internet but I did not find out any satisfying answers. I appreciate your helping. Thanks.

**Example:**

[image: Please see the example image here].

In this example, the red line on each bar implies the average value of its group.

To create the stacked horizontal bar chart, please see
https://jsfiddle.net/lamtn862004/9wm1krqf/10/.

```
  var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Dogs",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(237, 192, 169)",
      data: [20, 10, 25],
      stack: 1,
      xAxisID: 'x-axis-0',
      yAxisID: 'y-axis-0'
    },
    {
      label: "Cats",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(253, 234, 175)",
      data: [70, 85, 65],
      stack: 1,
      xAxisID: 'x-axis-0',
      yAxisID: 'y-axis-0'
    },
    {
      label: "Birds",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(179, 211, 200)",
      data: [10, 5, 10],
      stack: 1,
      xAxisID: 'x-axis-0',
      yAxisID: 'y-axis-0'

    },
    
  ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'groupableHBar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        type: 'category',
        id: 'y-axis-0'
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawTicks: true,
        },
        id: 'x-axis-0'
      },
      {
        stacked: true,
        position: 'top',
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true
        },
        id: 'x-axis-1',
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          drawTicks: true,
        },
        display: false
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Now, I want to add the average line to each bar (as shown in the image).

Also, do you know the other solutions with open-source libraries for doing this?

Comment: You can use the [`plugin API`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/developers/plugins.html) for that

Answer (score 0):

The lines can be drawn using [floating bars](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/floating.html) tied to the separate axis `y2`. To do so, you need to add another `dataset` as follows (I don't exactly understand what values you want to display, hence I randomly chose `40`, `65` and `55`):

```
{
  label: "Lines",
  backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  data: [40, 65, 55].map(v => [v - 0.3, v + 0.3]),
  yAxisID: 'y2',
  order: -1
}
```

Further you must define a new `scales` `option` as shown below:

```
y2: {
  display: false
}
```

Please take a look at your amended runnable code and see how it works.

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Dogs",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(237, 192, 169)",
      data: [20, 10, 25]
    },
    {
      label: "Cats",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(253, 234, 175)",
      data: [70, 85, 65]
    },
    {
      label: "Birds",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(179, 211, 200)",
      data: [10, 5, 10]
    },
    {
      label: "Lines",
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
      data: [40, 65, 55].map(v => [v - 0.3, v + 0.3]),
      yAxisID: 'y2',
      order: -1
    }
  ]
};

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      },
      y2: {
        display: false
      },
      x: {
        stacked: true,
        beginAtZero: true,
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```